# How to insert file path into mysql table using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am currently using mutler to upload the files to the server. Below is my query:

```
var insertSQL = "INSERT INTO ic_photos (icFrontURL,icBackURL,selfieURL,customer_id) VALUES ('" + frontICPath + "','"+backICPath + "','" + selfiePath + "','" + customerID + "')";
```

Console.log returns

```
"INSERT INTO ic_photos (icFrontURL,icBackURL,selfieURL,customer_id) VALUES ('public\images\frontIC_1526709299585_potato.png','public\images\backIC_1526709299595_potato2.jpg','public\images\selfie_1526709299596_potato3.jpg','41')"
```

But when it goes into mysql table, it shows the following value:

```
'publicimagesfrontIC_1526709040516_potato.png'
```

The slashes are missing. How can I fix this when I make the insert query ?

Answer (score 1):

This replaces the backslash with two backslashes. When it got inserted into the table, it will become one backslash

```
frontICPath = frontICPath.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

In most, if not all string-based interpretation environments, a backslash is considered a special character. To use a backslash explicitly, please use: "\\".

The two slashes above consist of 4 slashes in total through the text editor.